# Text area tag placeholder in Rails output raw value as text area value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.0.0.1
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

I am using Rails 5, When I try to set text area's placeholder it outputs the hash value instead of setting value for the placeholder.

```
<%= form_tag(new_project_note_path, method: 'POST') do %>
  <%= text_area_tag :content, placeholder: "Your note..." %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

Comment: use `<%= text_area_tag :content, "Your note..." %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_area_tag) `text_area_tag(name, content = nil, options = {})`

Second option is content. If you don't want to pass any content then make it nil.

Try like this.

```
<%= text_area_tag :content, :nil, placeholder: "Your note..." %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: According to current docs, it's `nil` and not `:nil` what you should pass as secord argument.

Answer (score 1):

`<%= text_area_tag :post, :"", placeholder: "Your note..."%>`

Hops this helps...

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
  <%= text_area_tag('fieldname', nil, placeholder: 'f4-thrilled', class:'XXX') %>
```